# “authorities” claim not added to jwt by default

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing an oauth2 solution based on Authorization Server 0.2.1, and noticed that “authorities” claim
not added to JWT by the authorization server by default.
i browsed to find a solution and found that need to configure a OAuth2TokenCustomizer bean, in order to add user’s “authorities” claim.

```
@Bean
OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
    return new JwtCustomizer();
}
```

this feels a bit like a workaround,and i wanted to verify that this solution is correct, and that the authorization server really doesn’t add the “authorities” claim by default and it is really required by us to implement the OAuth2TokenCustomizer.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Authorization Server implements the OAuth 2.1 spec. Since “authorities” is not part of the spec, that would constitute a customization that the application would provide, which is what the `OAuth2TokenCustomizer` is for. So you are correct, it is required.